# MySQL JOIN query worked in version 4, broken in 5

Tags: mysql, left-join

I've inherited a website someone else built using MySQL 4 as the database and am trying to switch to a new server, running MySQL 5. I copied all files across and dumped the database from MySQL version 4 and then imported back into version 5.

Now, half of the website is working while the other half is not. I keep getting the following:

> Unknown column 'a.id_art' in 'on clause'

Here's my query:

```
SELECT *, aks.nazwa as sekcja, ak.nazwa kategoria 
FROM 
artykuly a, 
artykuly_kategorie ak, 
artykuly_sekcje aks 
LEFT JOIN artykuly_addons aad ON aad.id_art=a.id_art 
WHERE a.id_art = '20' AND ak.id_sek = aks.id_sek AND a.id_kat = ak.id_kat
```

Why does the above work fine in MySQL version 4 but is a broken man in version 5?

Comment: Well, does `id_art` exist in `artykuly`?

Comment: This is more likely to be related to something that went wrong during the transfer (dump / reload) than differences between MySQL versions. Can you check if all tables exist, with the same columns first?

Comment: all tables exists also when i check id_art='20' there is such article in database

Comment: i'm no expert so i try simple things: what happens if you stop using the table aliases? as in `ON artykuly_addons.id_art=artykuly.id_art`

Answer (score 2):

Probably the combination of LEFT JOIN and joining with commas and filtering in the WHERE clause causes the problem. Try this:

```
SELECT *, aks.nazwa as sekcja, ak.nazwa kategoria 
FROM 
artykuly a INNER JOIN artykuly_kategorie ak ON a.id_kat = ak.id_kat 
INNER JOIN artykuly_sekcje aks ON ak.id_sek = aks.id_sek
LEFT JOIN artykuly_addons aad ON aad.id_art=a.id_art 
WHERE a.id_art = '20'
```

Comment: +1 for more details, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html, section "Join Processing Changes in MySQL 5.0.12"

Answer (score 0):

The precedence of the comma is now lower than explicit JOIN statements. Quoting the MySQL 5.0 [JOIN Syntax page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

> Previously, the comma operator (,) and JOIN both had the same
>   precedence, so the join expression t1, t2 JOIN t3 was interpreted as
>   ((t1, t2) JOIN t3). Now JOIN has higher precedence, so the expression
>   is interpreted as (t1, (t2 JOIN t3))

So previously this was treated as

```
SELECT *,
    aks.nazwa as sekcja,
    ak.nazwa kategoria 
FROM 
    (
        (
            artykuly a,
            artykuly_kategorie ak0
        ),
        artykuly_sekcje aks
    )
    LEFT JOIN artykuly_addons aad ON aad.id_art=a.id_art 
WHERE a.id_art = '20'
    AND ak.id_sek = aks.id_sek
    AND a.id_kat = ak.id_kat
```

Now it is interpreted as:

```
SELECT *,
    aks.nazwa as sekcja,
    ak.nazwa kategoria 
FROM 
    (
        (
            artykuly a,
            artykuly_kategorie ak0
        ),
        (artykuly_sekcje aks LEFT JOIN artykuly_addons aad ON aad.id_art=a.id_art)
    )
WHERE a.id_art = '20'
    AND ak.id_sek = aks.id_sek
    AND a.id_kat = ak.id_kat
```